# Tomcat 7 Access to the requested resource has been denied for REST put service

Tags: tomcat, web-application

I am building a REST Application on Tomcat 7 server.

using Application class for bootstrap.

Application class implementation as follows. Creating a singleton object of Resource01.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import com.somename.api.Resource01;


@ApplicationPath("/service")
public class AppConfig extends Application{
    public Set<Object> all_resources;
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons()
    {
        all_resources = new HashSet<Object>();
        Resource01 z = new Resource01();
        all_resources.add(z);
        return all_resources;
    }

}
```

Resource class is as follows.
I am providing support for 2 http methods PUT and GET.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("resource")
public class Resource01 {

    @GET
    @Path("mailer_status")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getMailStatus()
    {
        return "<h2>Mailer is in progress 14.47</h2>";
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("create_config")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMailConfig(String config)
    {
        //String instance_rep = m_config.toString();
        return "Payload Delivered";
    }

}
```

tomcat-users.xml is as follows.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>

  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

file is located at %CATALINA_HOME%/conf

I did some surfing/browsing for the failure reason and based on that I modified web.xml located in %CATALINA_HOME%/webapps/manager/WEB-INF

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
    <http-method>PUT</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>manager-gui</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <!-- Specifying a Secure Connection -->
  <user-data-constraint>
    <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL (forced SSL), INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Tomcat Manager Application</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

then i export the dynamic web project as a war file and deploy the war file.
for testing purpose, ARC(advanced rest client) is used.
at first i tried GET request - response is received. screenshot attached.
[GET Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dquE.png)
as could be seen in screenshot, 200 OK response is received. I am able to see desired string in browser.
when I try for PUT request.
I get 403 Forbidden error. I am attaching few screenshots which describes the same.
[PUT_REQUEST_HEADER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPLoo.png)
[PUT_REQUEST-PAYLOAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdTBk.png)
[PUT_RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7nTH.png)
any help/guidance is appreciated.
regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

i did not have a look at web.xml kept under conf folder.

there we had this

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>restricted methods</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<http-method>TRACE</http-method>
<http-method>PUT</http-method>
<http-method>DELETE</http-method>
<http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

I commented the PUT method.

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>restricted methods</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<http-method>TRACE</http-method>
<!--<http-method>PUT</http-method>-->
<http-method>DELETE</http-method>
<http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

and it worked !